# CSS border bottom has missing corners

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a long border underneath my menu UL, but the "border-bottom" property on the list items does not work well:

```css
#headermenu {
    height: 40px;
    background: #f47a20;
    position: relative;
}
#headermenu .menu {
    background: #F47B20;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #D66C1C;
    padding: 0.6em 1em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#headermenu-left {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0;
}
#headermenu-left .menu {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #004B8D;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="headermenu">
        <ul id="headermenu-left">
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

The border is interrupted at the corners by -I guess- the border-left and border-right properties not being there?

I can't put it on the `<ul>` element, because then the line runs too long.

Comment: Do you need the `ul` to be positioned absolutely for any reason other than to resolve this very problem?

Comment: @matewka the reason is for the borders yes, maybe not the best way but it works for me now.. Is there another thing I can learn to be better?

Comment: I think that j08691's answer is the best. I wanted to post similiar one but he was first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put it on the UL if you get rid of the width on it. Remove your last rule and use this:

```css
#headermenu {
    height: 40px;
    background: #f47a20;
    position: relative;
}
#headermenu .menu {
    background: #F47B20;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #D66C1C;
    padding: 0.6em 1em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#headermenu-left {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #004B8D;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="headermenu">
        <ul id="headermenu-left">
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This does work, although I needed the width (in my real code) to put another menu (-right) next to it and more to the right side. However, I could fix that by making that one `right: 10%` instead of its original `left: 70%; width: 30%;`

Answer (score 3):

The problem, as you suggest, is the missing left and right borders, which have a width, but no color, so this distorts the appearance of the bottom border with the illusion of a missing notch.

To solve this you can simply define `border-width: 0` for the element, and allow the `border-bottom` property to override that setting.

```css
#headermenu {
    height: 40px;
    background: #f47a20;
    position: relative;
}
#headermenu .menu {
    background: #F47B20;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #D66C1C;
    padding: 0.6em 1em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#headermenu-left {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0;
}
#headermenu-left .menu {
    border-width: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #004B8D;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="headermenu">
        <ul id="headermenu-left">
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="#">Link 6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This does work, but then I lose the fancy effect of defining the menu borders and everything is just links. It's a bit annoying that the bottom border has the others in its corners (although it also makes sense that it should).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is how borders work. Those are the ends of your border-left, and border-right. Here's a work around though, I added a div to the bottom of your list:

(I also removed your width:70%; from your list)

```
#bluebar {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BjGvp/6/

Comment: Is it okay to put a `div` inside an `ul` like that?

Comment: No, that's invalid HTML.

Comment: Not the greatest solution :) I'd rather have a div wrapped around the list, then put #bluebar in that div instead.